# What's the difference between だから, そこで and それで?

Tags: grammar

I've read that だから is more like a personal opinion which puts emphasis on the reason whereas それで is a more "natural" reason.

no idea about そこで though.

Answer (score 4):

だから focus on the reason, where そこで and それで sounds like you come up with the idea. Here is an example:

All the following sentences means “I am tried, so I take a rest.”

1. 私は疲れました。だから、私は休憩をとります。
2. 私は疲れました。そこで、私は休憩をとります。
3. 私は疲れました。それで、私は休憩をとります。

The first sentence with だから focus on the reason you take rest -- because you are tired. The second, and third sentence sounds like you are tired and you come up with the idea you want to take a rest.

そこで can not be used if the subject of the next sentence is not a living thing.

The following sentence means "I dropped a PC, so it has broken." But the second sentence is wrong because the subject is パソコン(PC).

1. 私はパソコンを落としました。だから、パソコンは壊れました。
2. (wrong) 私はパソコンを落としました。そこで、パソコンは壊れました。
3. 私はパソコンを落としました。それで、パソコンは壊れました。

Actually そこで also mean "at there", the second sentence with そこで can be interpreted as "I dropped a PC, it has broken at there." If you are talking about a location, the meaning of そこで change into "at there".

The following sentences all means "I went to a park. So I take a ride on a swing.", but second sentence with そこで also can interpreted as "I went to a park. I take a ride a swing there."

1. 私は公園に行きました。だから、私はブランコに乗りました。
2. 私は公園に行きました。そこで、私はブランコに乗りました。
3. 私は公園に行きました。それで、私はブランコに乗りました。